# Django's AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE changing the login success url?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_registration.MyUser"
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app_registration.MyUserProfile'
```

**models.py**

```
class MyUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, unique=True)
    ...
    MyUser.profile = property(lambda u: MyUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

**login.html**

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action=".">
....
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
</form>
```

So I've done this to create MyUserProfile model for my custom MyUser model.
Everything works fine, except for that when I login(localhost/accounts/login), the url is redirected to `htp://localhost:9999/accounts/profile` instead of the index page as I specified in the form's hidden input.

Where is this redirect url defined..??

Answer (score 6):

Use [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url):

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
>
> Default: '/accounts/profile/'
>
> The URL where requests are redirected after login when the
>   contrib.auth.login view gets no next parameter.
>
> This is used by the login_required() decorator, for example.